# Effect of partitioning on graph density and edge cuts

Tags: probability, data-visualization, graph-theory

When a graph is partitioned using partitioners like METIS, what 
are the expected effect on density (ratio of number of actual edges to the maximum total number of edges ) and edge cuts(comparison between each partition and graph before partitioning) when partitioned in different ways:
e.g. to get six partitions, two simple approaches could be:
1. directly partition the graph into six parts
2. first partition the graph into three partitions and then partition each of them into two parts.
[image]

I would be very thankful if someone can point to existing literature on this topic.